# What are the alternatives to resx file

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows application and I want to store all the texts for labels, radio buttons, buttons, check boxes, column headers of grid at one place. I have tried class file, xml file, database table and resource file.
I found that class file is the best way to store all these texts, but, I want to know is their any alternate way? If i am using class file then, i will have to recompile project if any text changes.
Please suggest me if you have know any a way other than resx, class file, xml file and database.

---

I came across Dictionary. I found that it is easier. If i use dictionary will it take my RAM space greater than using properties in class file?